# Why are my html buttons moving in I.E? They don't move in Chrome or FF

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

We are using AJAX to send data to our database. I've added some feedback for the user including a spinner (animated .gif) that spins during the request, and Pass/Fail text that is displayed to the user when the request is complete.

HTML:

```
<center>
    <table style="width:350px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:100px; min-width:100px;" align="right">
                <span id="spinner-and-text-displayed-here"></span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:150px">
                <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit();"/>
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel();"/>
            </td>
            <td style="width:100px"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
```

When the user clicks the submit button the spinner spins until the ajax callback is returned. At this point, the buttons do NOT shift. Once I receive the callback I display the text "Successful!" (displayed in the `span` using jQuery `$(el).html("Successful!");`), which causes the buttons to shift right. That message fades out (also using jquery), and once the button fades completely, the buttons shift back to their original position.

If I hardcode "Successful!" inside the span, the buttons are shifted, so I know it has something to do with the text (remember it doesn't shift when the spinner is displayed [which uses the `img` tag]).

It doesn't matter how wide i set the first `td` width.

Is there a way I can keep these buttons from shifting in IE?

Comment: -1 for using the center tag, -1 for using tables in a semantically inaccurate way, -1 for inline styles. Welcome to 2010, please update your coding standards.

Comment: ouch zzzzBov. To be fair, I inherited all this code. How about you update all the pages, there are only a couple hundred.

Comment: FWIW - Not a problem in IE8 except in compatibility mode. Also, I find this question very well worded :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `border-collapse:collapse;` to the `style` definition of the `table` and reduce the size of the middle cell.

```
<center>
    <table style="width:350px;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:100px; min-width:100px;" align="right">
                <span id="spinner-and-text-displayed-here"></span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:145px">
                <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit();"/>
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel();"/>
            </td>
            <td style="width:100px"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
```

Comment: Wow this actually worked (to my surprise). It took both the `border-collapse:collapse` style as well as reducing the middle cell's width in order to work (just like you said).  Thanks Jonathan

Comment: @Darcy as the HTML you posted looks quite old I assumed that you were working on something legacy so made the above suggestion to target just that block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `DOCTYPE` to your file, e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>

<body>
    <table style="width:350px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:100px; min-width:100px;" align="right">
                <span id="el"></span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:150px">
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="$('#el').html('Success');"/>
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel();"/>
           </td>
           <td style="width:100px"></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I had a similar issue and it was because of IE handling the  tag differently from other browsers.